# Tell if Android Notification Bar is Split

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Is there a way in android to tell what the width of the notification bar is going to be? I am mainly curious because on a tablet, the notification bar can be split and only use up half of the screens width.

So programatically, is there a sure fire way of determining what the width (in dp) of the notification bar will be? Or alternatively, is there a way to tell if the notification bar is being split?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to find that out. In most cases you do not really need that information anyway, as framework will take care of showing the notification in the similar way, despite of screen size (that's why on tablet it's not stretched to screen width as it'd look odd)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the information is not needed? I did notice that the notification looks smaller, is it scaling that down in dp as well?